# How to select row of QTableWidget with double click?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

This is my code before

```
ui.tableWidget->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
ui.tableWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
```

With this I can select the row with only one click, and double click to edit the cell of table. Now I want to do the other way around, one click to edit the cell and double click to select the row.

For one click to edit, the code should be

```
ui.tableWidget->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::AllEditTriggers);
```

But for double click to select the row, I don't know yet. Can you help me?

Comment: I'm sure you know you are doing, but this is the complete opposite behavior than what I have seen and done in desktop, web and mobile apps.

Comment: @UmNyobe: Yeah, I know, but this is the requirement. I have same idea as yours, but I dont have the choice. :(

Comment: I've been there :(

Answer (score 0):

To catch click and double click you can do this:

```
connect(ui.tableWidget, &QTableWidget::cellClicked, this, &cellClicked);
connect(ui.tableWidget, &QTableWidget::cellDoubleClicked, this, &cellDoubleClicked);
```

In this case `cellClicked` and `cellDoubleClicked` are your functions. You can do anything in these functions:

1) select a row:

```
void MyClass::cellDoubleClicked(int iRow, int iColumn)
{
  ui.tableWidget->setRangeSelected(QTableWidgetSelectionRange(iRow, 0, iRow, ui.tableWidget->columnCount() - 1), 1);
}
```

2) open editor (use `QTableWidget::openPersistentEditor`)

Comment: thanks for your help. Could you explain clearer? I still don't know how to define `rowIdx` and define function `cellDoubleClicked`.

Comment: thank you. I defined like this, but there was error with `&cellDoubleClicked` in `connect`: "invalid operation on an expression of a bound member function".